# Next.js app router: fetch data at build time in Dynamic rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rendering, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

I am using next@13.5.6 and App router. I use fetch with `{ cache: 'no-store' }` and expect that data will not fetch at **build** time. Because if I set `{ cache: 'no-store' }` rendering become to be **Dynamic** and

> With Dynamic Rendering, routes are rendered for each user at the request time.

But the result is different, my console.logs triggered during build time.
I can fix this problem with `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';`, but I want to understand, why my example doesn't work.
Also, it works as expected in next@13.0.0

Appreciate your answers.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-gwen-5fh28s?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.js%3A1%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00083b6lt3powly7%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00033b6l0g21ednq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00053b6lydztyxmi%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00073b6lt6m7xlo9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clopm6jyc00033b6l0g21ednq%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00033b6l0g21ednq%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopm6r95003y3b6lwcxtgir5%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00023b6lu864fg67%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fpage.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6r95003y3b6lwcxtgir5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fnext.config.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopokn6z06ow3b6l51dr33o6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Flayout.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopoolad072v3b6l489cpysb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clopm6jyc00073b6lt6m7xlo9%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00063b6l9fl5iumq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00073b6lt6m7xlo9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00063b6l9fl5iumq%2522%257D%252C%2522clopm6jyc00053b6lydztyxmi%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00053b6lydztyxmi%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6jyc00043b6lkjgqulth%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clopm6vgf004n3b6lmbpg3qvz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clopm6vgf004n3b6lmbpg3qvz%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

How to reproduce:

1. start build
2. look in the console after the build

Main component app/page.js

```js
const getPosts = async () => {
  const posts = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
    cache: "no-store",
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  console.log(posts);
  for (const post of posts) {
    await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${post.id}`, {
      cache: "no-store",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(console.log);
  }
  console.log("fetched");
  return posts;
};

export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return <h1>The Starting Page</h1>;
}
```

Result:
[image]